# Python requests error (Unexpected EOF) for longer responses

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, pyopenssl

When I use the requests package to retrieve a response which is over about 185KB, I get the error below (only the tail shown).  Shorter responses to the same URL work fine.  This is with Python 2.7, requests 2.7.0, pyOpenSSL 0.15.1 and urllib3 1.10.4.

```
In [42]: req = requests.post(url, headers, params=data)

    /usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.pyc in _read_chunked(self, amt)
    601                 value.append(self._safe_read(chunk_left))
    602             elif amt < chunk_left:
--> 603                 value.append(self._safe_read(amt))
    604                 self.chunk_left = chunk_left - amt
    605                 return ''.join(value)

/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.pyc in _safe_read(self, amt)
    656         s = []
    657         while amt > 0:
--> 658             chunk = self.fp.read(min(amt, MAXAMOUNT))
    659             if not chunk:
    660                 raise IncompleteRead(''.join(s), amt)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.pyc in read(self,     size)
    144                 # fragmentation issues on many platforms.
    145                 try:
--> 146                     data = self._sock.recv(left)
    147                 except OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError:
    148                     continue

SysCallError: (-1, 'Unexpected EOF')
```

The URL is: https://secure.networkmerchants.com/api/query.php

The query also works fine, regardless of the data size, if I return to the way I did it before the requests package was available to me.  That is using urllib2.

Comment: Why are you mixing requests with urllib? Doesn't the requests's GET function work for you?

Comment: @jcoppens, requests uses urllib3

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, I knew that. But wouldn't the first post already have read the reply (i.e. wouldn't `req` already contain the reply?

Comment: have you tried using the timeout parameter?

Comment: @John I did try using the timeout and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: @jcoppens I think this is the usual way of using Python to do http.  Also this works fine (same URL, same headers) for sufficiently short responses.

Comment: @Mitch Not that I have *that* much experience, but in the course of a couple of projects, I used `requests` I didn't touch urllib3 at all. `Requests` now supports chunked transfer in both directions. Code gets so much cleaner.

Comment: @jcoppens I'm not doing anything with urllib3.  I mentioned the version because it is used by requests. The only call I make is the one I show above - requests.post.

Comment: @Mitch I must be in dire need of a vacation... My apologies for the urlllib3 confusion. I did a few tests, using requests to download 500kB+ images over normal http: and https:, but that didn't give any problems. I don't have an url where I can do a post for a large file. Did you try to enable debugging as described here: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#api-changes

Comment: @jcoppens Good suggestion, but did not yield any insight.  The debug information generated is the same for both a short response (which works) and a long response (which doesn't).  From the traceback, I suspect an issue with the socket.

Comment: @Mitch Well, this seems to exceed my knowledge. A last cry would be to run Wireshark on the connection, and see if there is indication of problems at a lower protocol level.

Comment: @Mitch I'd also recommend trying a previous version of `requests` (excluding the version 2.6.x, which contained a bug - I believe in the chunking part). You could install an older version and force using it by adding `__requires__ = ["requests==2.2.1"]; import pkg_resources`. I had to do this before 2.7 came out.